# C#: Fill DataGridView with List of Class Objects

Tags: c#, list, class, datagridview, rows

I have the following class which fills a list as shown bellow from an event when a button bound to each column is clicked on a DataGridView called MenuGrid:

```
public class orderedfood
{
     public string price;
     public string item;
}
List<orderedfood> order = new List<orderedfood>();
private void MenuGrid_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
     order.Add(new orderedfood { item = MenuGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), price = subtotal.ToString() });
}
```

This MenuGrid has the following format: 
[image]

What I want to do is to reload the DataGridView bound to the order List, hence I tried the following code:

```
        MenuGrid.DataSource = null;
        MenuGrid.Rows.Clear();


        for (int i = 0; i < order.Count; i++)
        {
            MenuGrid.Rows.Add(order[i].item, order[i].price);


        }
        MenuGrid.Refresh();
```

This gives the following output, which is not what I want:

[image]

The final screenshot is correct on the number of rows but it doesn't include the name and the price of the the item.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why are you setting the datasource to null? set the datasource to `order`

Answer (score 0):

Dont set DataSource to null. And also you can try this inside your for loop,

```
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
            dataGridView1.Rows.Insert(0, order[i].item, order[i].price);
```